Youtube video downloadet in next.js
Here is the api endpoint:
import ytdl from 'ytdl-core';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { url = '' }: { url?: string } = req.query;
  const video = ytdl(url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mp4');
  video.pipe(res);
}

here is the front end function
const handleDownload = async (url: string) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`/api/downloader?url=${url}`, {
      responseType: 'blob'
    });
    
    const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'audio/mp4' });
    const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadUrl;
    link.download = 'audio.mp4';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Download failed:', error);
    // Handle error (e.g., show error message to user)
  }
};

how can I handle the response in the front end? I am getting this error:

I think the issue is the API endpoint what did I get wrong?

Please use replit or other online tool for create a [mre].
